# Can't Access MongoDB instance hosted in Google Cloud VM from RoboMongo

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, robo3t

I have created a project and deployed MEAN stack by using "Click to Deploy". When I visit <> / 3000 I do see the MEAN page coming from the server. Also I can ssh to that machine and see all the stuff there. I can access MongoDB instance in that way.

I also created a separate VM where I installed Node.JS and MongoDB myself. Both working similar way.

My problem is - I can't access either of the machines from my local RoboMongo Instance neither I can access them from local shell. I had similar issue in aws world and solution was to create security group to permit the mongodb port (27017). So I tried that and added "Firewall rule" under "Network" and allowed that port for all incoming traffics --> as bellow

mongodb communication from outside
Source Ranges:
0.0.0.0/0
Allowed Protocols or Ports:
tcp:27017
But the issue persists and I can't access the mongodb instance from robomongo or local shell.

Any idea ?

Comment: Seems like somehow the specific port is not being exposed. I get  Failed to connect to <<Ip Address>> port <<port>>: Connection refused - while the port is open in network - firewall

Answer (score 1):

You should config bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 when start mongod
eg
mongod.conf as folowing

```
fork = true
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
quiet = true
dbpath = /srv/mongodb
logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
logappend = true
journal = true
```

and start mongo as this command

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Now you can connect Mongo on Google cloud VM through external IP with 27017 as port.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check if your MongoDB is listening on port 27017 by running the following command:

```
sudo netstat -nap | grep 27017
```

I suggest also that you try to turn off your IP tables on the VM and try to access maybe a rule is blocking your access.
One thing also to check is your *bindIp* using *db.serverCmdLineOpts()*

Comment: MongoDB is listening to 27017 for sure.
Let me check the IPTables